# store a matrix (or a 2D array)as values for each key in a dictionary

Tags: python, grasshopper

I have the following table coming from SQL:

```
b_num   loc max_neg_m   
10    0.89  -480050 
10    0.93  -144107 
10    0.96  -364381 
10    1     -699219 
100   0     -904713 
100   0.2   -772981 
100   0.41  -645617 
100   0.5   -563448 
100   0.67  -520747 
100   1     -218334 
1000  0     -112367 
1000  0.05  15976
```

with a python code, I'm looking to store a 2D array of loc, max_neg_m for each unique b_num.

```
a=dict()

a.keys(b_num)

a.values=[loc,max_neg_m]
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, storing 2D arrays as dictionary values is absolutely possible. Do this:

```py
dictionary = {}

# Replace ``sql_query_result`` with the appropriate value.
for b_num, loc, max_neg_m in sql_query_result:
    if b_num not in dictionary.keys():
        dictionary[b_num] = []

    dictionary[b_num].append([loc, max_neg_m])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm reluctant to say much because I'm a bit confused by the three lines of code you've given. If they're meant to be an idea of the end result, then perhaps sort of schematically:

Create your dictionary 'a' as an empty dictionary.

Then cycle through your b_num, testing the dictionary to see if the dictionary has the current b_num as a key.

If it does, append the associated [loc, max_neg_m] to that dictionary value.

If it does not, assign the key-value pair of the key and an empty array, then pretend the dictionary does have the key (because now it does!).

Comment: something like this is my desired outcome: dict={"10":([0.89,0.93,0.96,1],[-480050 ,-144107 ,-364381,-699219 ])} sorry if my notation is wrong, I'm not sure if this is even possible to have a matrix as a dict values.